# Largest eigenvalue of a $A^T A$ matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a large real matrix A of size $40K\times 400K$, is there an efficient way to calculate the largest eigenvalue of $A^T A$ (size $400K\times 400K$)?

Thanks.

Comment: What is $A'$? The transpose?

Comment: Indeed, the transpose. Ill clarify, thanks.

Comment: For what it is worth, this is equal to the largest eigenvalue of $AA^{T}$ (size $40K\times 40K$).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you want the eigenvalue of largest magnitude (not the largest positive eigenvalue) the most efficient algorithm is power iteration: pick an initial vector $v_0$, then iterate

$$v_i = A^T\left(A\frac{v_{i-1}}{\|v_{i-1}\|}\right).$$

Then $\|v_i\|$ will converge almost surely to the largest magnitude eigenvalue of $A^TA$.

EDIT: Notice that computing $A^TA$ is exceedingly expensive and does not need to be done; the utility of power iteration is that it finds the largest eigenvalue using only matrix-vector products. I've added parentheses to clarify.

EDIT 2: Of course, since $A^TA$ is symmetric positive-semidefinite, the eigenvalues are nonnegative and the largest magnitude eigenvalue is also the largest eigenvalue.

Comment: The problem is that it is too big for me to even calculate $A^T$.

Comment: Note that you never explicitly compute $A^TA.$ You only need to compute matrix-vector products $Ax$ and $A^Tx$. If these operations are too expensive... you're out of luck, I'm afraid.

Comment: @user7530, Can you clarify what you mean by "almost surely"? If it does converge, how are you supposed to know if it or isn't the largest magnitude eigenvalue? Regards

Comment: Assuming $A^TA$ has a unique largest magnitude eigenvalue, power iteration will converge to it unless the starting vector $v_0$ is orthogonal to the corresponding eigenvector. There is no way to be sure, but you can always repeat the algorithm with a different seed $v_0$ and check that the results agree.

Comment: @ido If the vector that you chose doesn't lie in the subspace perpendicular to the largest magnitude eigenvalue (possibly subspace), then the value will converge. This probability of this happening has measure 0, since it is a proper subspace. You could take 10 (or 100) linearly independent vectors.

Comment: Maybe I did something wrong? I tried as a toy example to take A of size 30*30 and then iterate $v:=A^T\cdot A\cdot v$ but the norm of $v$ exploded to infinity really fast... and the eigenvalues of $A^T\cdot A$ are finite.

Comment: You must normalize the vector before you multiply: $\widehat{v_{i-1}} = v_{i-1}/\|v_{i-1}\|$.

Comment: All eigenvalues of $A^TA$ are nonnegative, so we really are looking for the largest eigenvalue.  Edit: Oh, I see now that you mention that in the end of the answer, but I was thrown off by the first sentence of your answer, where it says "not the largest positive eigenvalue," when in fact it is the largest positive eigenvalue.

Comment: @user7530: You should include the normalization in your answer; it is incorrect as written.

Comment: Hm? The normalization is there.

Comment: @user7530: My mistake, my incorrect reading.  I somehow missed the hat notation in the answer, or forgot to incorporate its definition given in the comment.  Sorry for the noise. (In case you aren't aware, you can let users receive automatic notifications of comment replies using the format @username.)

Comment: @Jonas I've edited the answer in case the hat notation isn't standard